# addEventListener firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, blob

So I'm trying to convert a blob to an actual file. To reduce the thread load I made worker.js file which listens to an event and then pushes the event data to an array and finally converts it to the blob.

```
function download() {
    setGotFile(false);
            
    const dwn = function (event) {
        let stream = event.data.stream();
        console.log(stream);
        const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(fileNameRef.current);
        console.log(fileStream);
        stream.pipeTo(fileStream);
        stream = null;
    }
    worker.postMessage("download");
    worker.addEventListener("message", dwn,false)

}
```

The download function works fine for the first time. But then if triggered the event is getting added up which makes it download the file multiple times.

The worker.js file:-

```
let array = [];
self.addEventListener("message", event => {
    console.log(array);     
    if (event.data === "download") {
        const blob = new Blob(array);
        self.postMessage(blob);         
        array = [];
    } else {
        array.push(event.data);        
    }
})
```

Comment: Every call to `.addEventListener()` adds **another** listener, so when the next event shows up all of the added listeners will fire.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the adding up of these event listeners? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well you could keep a counter or a flag to indicate that a listener has already been added, or you could rearrange the logic in some other way, but if you think about it that's why the method is called "**add** event listener"

Comment: Yeah, one method I was thinking was to somehow overwrite the event listeners.

Comment: The other way to look at it is that you only need to add the worker event handler *once*.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the hint . Managed to add it once now the code works.